# "Has the bus arrived yet"?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, present-participles

"Yet" could mean "so far/by now" and "now". But if say "Has the bus arrived yet"? Does here "yet" mean so far/by now or now?

Comment: Please don't use the `british-english` or `american-english` tags unless you're specifically asking about usage in those dialects, or about the difference between them.

Comment: @stangdon Next time i will keep that in mind. thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey my apology i could not understand your answer in relevance to my question. Could you pls simplify it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities to the meaning of this question.

1. You are on the bus but are unsure where it is currently. You want to know if it has arrived at your destination. *"Has the bus arrived [at Mytown] yet?"*
2. You are waiting for the bus, but out of sight of the place where you expect it to stop. You want to know if it has arrived or not. *"Has the bus arrived [at the bus stop] yet?"*

Comment: thank you but I am still not clear whether  "Yet" means  "by now/so far" or "now" as in my or your examples?

Comment: @BilalZafar  Try asking each of the questions but substitute your possibilities. The only one that I think makes sense in these two contexts is "now".  See Merriam Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet definition 2.(a),2 which I think is the closest, "at this or that time". Also see synonyms at https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/yet which give you some more words to try in place of "yet". "Finally" and "at last" seem to be closest with similar meaning.

Comment: If you ask whether something has happened **yet**, you are waiting for it to happen. Maybe you are worried that the bus has already passed by and you have missed it.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that's a better explanation and it also applies to the other situation when you are on the bus.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, their meanings are similar but their connotations and usages can be different. [This](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/already-still-or-yet?q=Already%2C%20still%20or%20yet) may help you.

Comment: "Their meanings"? The OP is only asking after the meaning of 'yet'. And please relay the relevant information from the link to your answer.

Comment: @Joachim yes indeed.

Comment: I meant that the differences between yet, until now, so far, already, and so on could be subtle. According to Oxford languages, yet is an adverb that means "up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then". When clicking "This" link, you would see a sentence "Is your sister at university yet?" that suggests "I expect that she will go to university. Is she there now?". "Yet" implys expectation while basically meaning "until now". The link also provides other usages of yet and others similar words. Hope "This" helps.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately "This" doesn't tell me the name of the source, nor what it says. Answers consisting of a link are not helpful because links rot over time, websites close down, change domain or modify the original text. You should copy and past the excerpt that supports your answer.